# external javascript file from asp.net C# page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have some javascript functions written in an external javascript file.
and i have included the file in my asp.net page head section.
however i m not able to understand how do i call the functions from the code behind file.
e.g, i want to call a certain function 'tacount' on onkeypress event of a textbox. how can i possible do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call [client side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side) functions from [server side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side) code.

You *could* emit javascript to call these functions from your server side code, but this can get very messy.

Instead of attaching javascript functions to *server side* events, do so on the client side.

Use a library such as jQuery to attach the event to your textbox on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) at all the javascript calls you can make from code behind but basically all you have to do in your code behind call the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.getType(),"tacount",'tacount();',true);
```

This will then be triggered once the post back is completed on the client side, it is however advised to rather call javascript only from client side.

**EDIT**:

The fact that your file is in an external javascript file does not matter given that the browser will call it the same as inline javascript.

All you have to do is call the function as usual in your designer code i.e.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" onkeypress='return tacount();'/>
```

Comment: But first make sure that's this script isn't already registered on the page

Comment: i want to call javascript from the client side only. for that what needs to be done???

Comment: I've updated my answer; Paste your designer code with the textbox name and the function you want to call if you need more help

Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" onkeypress='return tacount();'/>
the onkeypress event doenst show up as an event of textbox. this is precisely the problm.

Comment: the intellisense won't bring it up because it's not supported in visual studio, but it will work because it will be inserted as an attribute on your input box in your html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a JavaScript function from your Code Behind file, you should use the code as suggested by @TBohnen.jnr i.e. :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.getType(),"fnMyFunctionNameFromServiceSide_tacount",'tacount();',true);
```

However, you should note that the `fnMyFunctionNameFromServiceSide_tacount` should not be present in your markup code or any included javascript file.

If you want to call the javascript function from an externally included javascript file use the following code:

```
<asp:TextBox id="myTextBox" runat="server" onkeypress="javascript: return tacount();"/>
```

However, if the above does not work for you then it means that the function could not be found. In this case I would suggest you to use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug) to find the exact cause for not finding the javascript function. Could be that the function itself is not present or there is some javascript error inside the function itself.

Hope this helps.